# Understanding bitwise operation in this example

Tags: javascript, quicksort, bitwise-operators

I'm studying some common algorithms implementations in JavaScript, and found this one while looking for quicksort:
https://rawgit.com/escherba/algorithms-in-javascript/master/src/quickmiddle-sort.js

It implements an array partition function as well:

```
function partition(array, left, right) {
        var pivot = array[(left + right) >>> 1];
        while (left <= right) {
            while (array[left] < pivot) { left++; }
            while (array[right] > pivot) { right--; }
            if (left <= right) {
                var temp = array[left];
                array[left++] = array[right];
                array[right--] = temp;
            }
        }
        return left;
}
```

I wonder what is the math behind the bitwise operation, I'm quite a newbie with them.

Comment: It's not really necessary in JS, probably borrowed from Java code where it *is* necessary

Comment: @harold Is it for optimization purposes?

Comment: If it is there intentionally, then that's the only thing it can be for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, you are asking about this part

```
(left + right) >>> 1
```

There is an addition of two operands and a [zero-fill shift right `>>>` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#>>>_(Zero-fill_right_shift)) with one bit.

For example you have the value `9` and shift one bit to right.

> ```
>       9 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
>                    --------------------------------
> 9 >>> 1 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000000100 (base 2) = 4 (base 10)
> ```

The result is an integer number of `4`.

Comment: Yes, just tried in console now, imagined it something like this. Thank you, clear explanation!

Answer (score 2):

shift right by 1 is exactly like divide by 2 you can test it by yourself . right a number in a binary and do a right shift and check the result

Comment: Ah, I see. So basically we avoid the usage of a division function to be faster?

Comment: Yes 4 in binary is 100 shift right you loose the 0 the least significant bit so we end up with 10 binary which is 2 decimal :) it's faster that normal division

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operation is nothing but dividing the sum of left and right values by 2.
if left=2 and right=7 output is 9/2 and truncated to 4.